# Responsive carousel according to browser height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How would you resize a carousel according to browser's height ?

For resizing according to width, Im able to make it responsive with this in CSS

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

But for making it responsive towards height, im not sure how would I do it.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css unit `vh` for using screen height purposes. 100vh means whole viewport height. vh is dynamic so it changes as you change the screen size.

Here is one demo from [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TdVu/772/)

```
.carousel .item {
    max-width: 100%; /*slider width*/
    max-height: 100vh; /*slider height*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sachin Kanungo.

I had the same issue as Max. 
But for me it worked with these settings:

```
.carousel {
   height: 80vh; /*slider height equals to 80% of viewport height*/
   margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.carousel .item {
   min-width:100%;
   height:80vh; /*slider height equals to 80% of viewport height*/
   background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   height: 80vh; /*slider height equals to 80% of viewport height*/
}
```

Note: I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6